# Positioning a figure in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a figure consisting of many PDFs that I uploaded into Illustrator. I want to remove one of the PDFs and replace it. How can I set the exact position and size of the new PDF so that it has the same position as the old one? Also, is there a "Send to Back" option similar to PowerPoint?

Comment: Welcome! I don't really understand "figure consisting of many PDFs". PDFs, by nature, are *singular*. They may contain *pages* but are generally not comprised of separate, individual, objects in a manner which allows individual selecting. What do you mean by "figure"? And Illustrator's main menu: `Object > Arrange` contains the arrangement operations.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my nomenclature is wrong. I meant I uploaded multiple PDFs into the same file. Would object be a better word?

Answer (score 0):

If you have placed the PDF as a linked file in Illustrator, you can simply relink to the new PDF.  This will retain the position and scaling of the old one (assuming both PDFs are the same size obviously).

Here's how . . .

Select the PDF, then in the options along the top, right click on the linked file name, and choose "Relink" from the dropdown.

[image]

When the Place dialog pops up, navigate to your new PDF file, and select it, then hit Place.

**OR**

If you've embedded the PDF instead, you could use guides to mark its position. Delete it, add the new PDF, and position and rescale according to the guides.

As to your second question, yes Illustrator has *Object > Arrange > Send to Back*